# Create a variable conditioned on other column

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I'd like to create a conditional new_column from 2 existing columns. Existing columns must contain either 0 or 1. I had some ideas about loops already which are not working.

In a nutshell, if `column1` has a number equal to 1 and `column2` has a number equal to 0, then `new_column` will be 0 and only equal to 1 if both columns are 1).

**desired output**

```
Column1  column2  new_column
  1        0         0
  0        0         0
  1        1         1
```

I am a newbie to R.

I have already tried several topics such as:

- [creating a new column from an existing column using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174798/creating-a-new-column-from-an-existing-column-using-r)
- [Using do loops in R to create new variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248778/using-do-loops-in-r-to-create-new-variables)
- [R Data.Table create a variable with a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610692/r-data-table-create-a-variable-with-a-condition)

I want to thanks the R community for their help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about  [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and how to give a  [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) . This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what about if column2 is 1 and column1 is 0? Should column3 also be 0? If that is the case you can simply just do:

```
df$column3 <- df$column1*df$column2
```

In this case, if one (or both) of the two columns is 0, the third one also be 0 and if both are 1, the third one will be 1.

Comment: what if I want to create the 3rd column on different conditions: now, the first column has to be one and the second 0 for the 3rd one to be 1 and 0 in any other case.

Comment: Then just do: ifelse(column1 == 1 & column2 == 0, 1, 0)

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look beyond 0 or 1 where multiplying may not be perfectly suitable the try this;

```
df$col3 <- 0 
df$col3[df$col1 == 1 & df$col2 ==1] <- 1
```